# Open .bin file in R

Tags: r, file, binary

I have seen several questions about writing `.bin` (binary) files from R, but I am wondering what function or package R has that could read in `.bin` files?

Is R capable of reading in `.bin` files?

Comment: What exactly is in your `bin` files? I don't believe that a standard,universal file format. What program is making these bin files?

Comment: I unfortunately don't know what wrote them or what is in them. I was just told to try to explore them. I tried using `readBin()` and declared `integer()` the first time and `"numeric"` the second time and it resulted in a single string of numbers (but different numbers depending on what I declared)..

Comment: A binary file is just a bunch of bytes. In order to decode it, you need to know what those bytes are supposed to represent. They could be integers, float values, characters, or any combination of the former. There's no way to extract the data for a file where you don't know how it was encoded. There is no general way to read an arbitrary binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `hexView` package, and you need to know a lot about the content of the files.

Dump the bytes using `hexView::viewRaw(readRaw(filename))`, then figure out the structure using what you know about the file.  Then figure out what is in there, and use a more specific dump function like `viewFormat`.  See the package documentation.

It's a lot of work, and requires a lot of knowledge specific to the creation of the file.  You're unlikely to succeed, but that's how you should do it.